# Visual Studio 2010 - Slow Update of Syntax Highlighting

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2010

I'm generally happy with VS2010 but have one gripe - the syntax highlighting is very slow in updating so quite often incorrectly hightlights lines of code I have corrected. Building the app fixes it, but sometimes (e.g. when writing Javascript) I don't want to rebuild. Can anyone point me in the direction of a fix?

FYI I'm running  Windows 7 x64 natively (ie. via Bootcamp) on a MacPro with 8GB RAM and 8 cores. Also got 4GB of Readyboost in there so there aren't many excuses ...

Comment: Adding this as a comment since I don't like it as an answer. I've encountered this several times as well, and for me at least, it seems to be related to how long I've had that instance of VS2010 open.  I've only encountered the problem with instances that have been open for days, and closing VS2010 and restarting has always resolved it for me.  YMMV

Comment: It does indeed seem to resolve the issue, but this is at least as much of a pain as rebuilding the project :-(